# Проблема закрытия файла fclose (язык С)

Tags: c, файлы, структуры

По заданию мне нужно считать базу данных из файла .txt в поля структуры. По отладчику смотрела, что все хорошо записывается(в сами структуры). Но при закрытии файла ловлю exception.

```
3456109
Kirov
Nikolay
Olegovich
M
12
12
1993
184
86
Minsk
guitar playing, painting
smoking
Surgeon
20
25
-
```

Это пример информации из файла для записи в поля структуры (последующие лежат в таком же виде, начиная со следующей строки)
[image: Возникает в файле компилятора].
На строке fclose(f) ломается. Может кто знает, в чем может быть проблема?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h > 
#define LINE 1024

typedef struct DateOfBirth {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

typedef struct Human {
    char id[7];        //регистрационный номер
    char surname[20];   //фамилия
    char name[20];      //имя
    char patronymic[20];  //отчество
    char sex[2];  //пол
    DateOfBirth dateOfBirth;  //дата рождения
    int height;   //рост
    int weight;   //вес
    char city[15];   //город
    char interests[30]; //интересы
    char badHabits[20]; //вредные привычки
    char textMyself[30];  //информация о себе
    int prefAgeMin;  //желаемый диапазон возраста
    int prefAgeMax;
    char prefBadHab[20];      //желаемые вредные привычки
};

long checkSize() {
    FILE * f;
    errno_t err;
    int linesCount = 0;
    err = fopen_s(&f, "database.txt", "r"); //проверка на нахождение файла и его открытие
    if (err) {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        _getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        char *tempBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000000);
        while (!feof(f)) {
            fgets(tempBuffer, 100, f);
            linesCount++;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return linesCount / 17;

}

Human* readingFromFile(int lines) {
    FILE *f;
    Human *human = (Human*)malloc(sizeof(Human)*lines);
    errno_t err;
    err = fopen_s(&f, "database.txt", "r"); //проверка на нахождение файла и его открытие
    if (err) {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        fclose(f);
        _getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines && !feof(f) && human; i++)
        {
            fscanf_s(f, "%s", human[i].id, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%s", human[i].surname, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%s", human[i].name, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%s", human[i].patronymic, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%s", human[i].sex, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%d", &human[i].dateOfBirth.day, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%d", &human[i].dateOfBirth.month, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%d", &human[i].dateOfBirth.year, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%d", &human[i].height, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%d", &human[i].weight, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%s", human[i].city, LINE);
            fseek(f, 2, SEEK_CUR);
            fgets(human[i].interests, 100, f);
            int pos = strcspn(human[i].interests, "\n");
            human[i].interests[pos] = '\0';
            fgets(human[i].badHabits, 100, f);
            pos = strcspn(human[i].badHabits, "\n");
            human[i].badHabits[pos] = '\0';
            fgets(human[i].textMyself, 100, f);
            pos = strcspn(human[i].textMyself, "\n");
            human[i].textMyself[pos] = '\0';
            fscanf_s(f, "%d", &human[i].prefAgeMin, LINE);
            fscanf_s(f, "%d", &human[i].prefAgeMax, LINE);
            fseek(f, 2, SEEK_CUR);
            fgets(human[i].prefBadHab, 100, f);
            pos = strcspn(human[i].prefBadHab, "\n");
            human[i].prefBadHab[pos] = '\0';
        }
        if (fclose(f) == EOF)
            printf("bbooom\n");
        else
            printf("done\n");
        return human;
    }
}

void printOnConsole(Human **human, int size) {
    printf("\n%7s |%10s |%10s |%10s |%4s |%13s |%3s |%3s |%10s |%15s |%12s |%21s |%6s |%6s |%9s", "Id", "Surname", "Name", "Patronymic", "Sex", "Birthday", "H", "W", "City", "Interests", "Habbits", "SelfInfo", "MinAge", "MaxAge", "WantedHab");
    int i = 0;
    while (i != size) {
        printf("\n%7s |%10s |%10s |%10s |%4s |%3d/%3d/%5d |%3d |%3d |%10s |%15s |%12s |%21s |%6d |%6d |%9s", human[i]->id, human[i]->surname, human[i]->name, human[i]->patronymic, human[i]->sex, human[i]->dateOfBirth.day, human[i]->dateOfBirth.month, human[i]->dateOfBirth.year, human[i]->height, human[i]->weight, human[i]->city, human[i]->interests, human[i]->badHabits, human[i]->textMyself, human[i]->prefAgeMin, human[i]->prefAgeMax, human[i]->prefBadHab);
        i++;
    }
}

void loadToFile(Human **human, int lines) {
    FILE *f;
    errno_t err;
    err = fopen_s(&f, "database2.txt", "w"); //проверка на нахождение файла и его открытие
    if (err) {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        fclose(f);
        _getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines && human; i++)
        {
            fprintf_s(f, "%s", human[i]->id, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%s", human[i]->surname, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%s", human[i]->name, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%s", human[i]->patronymic, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%s", human[i]->sex, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%d", &human[i]->dateOfBirth.day, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%d", &human[i]->dateOfBirth.month, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%d", &human[i]->dateOfBirth.year, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%d", &human[i]->height, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%d", &human[i]->height, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%d", &human[i]->weight, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%s", human[i]->city, LINE);
            fseek(f, 2, SEEK_CUR);
            fputs(human[i]->interests, f);
            fputs(human[i]->badHabits, f);
            fputs(human[i]->textMyself, f);
            fprintf_s(f, "%d", &human[i]->prefAgeMin, LINE);
            fprintf_s(f, "%d", &human[i]->prefAgeMax, LINE);
            fseek(f, 2, SEEK_CUR);
            fputs(human[i]->prefBadHab, f);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size = checkSize();
    Human *human = readingFromFile(size);
    printOnConsole(&human, size);
    loadToFile(&human, size);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не к вашей ошибке - но "уж сколько раз твердили миру" - `while (!feof(f))` - это неверно...

Comment: Пожалуйста, в следующий раз ставьте ещё тег "VC" :)

Comment: Будьте добры, приведите ещё пример файла, у которого корректное для обработки содержимое, если можно :)

Comment: Добавила пример из файла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас куча ошибок и недочётов, и поэтому непонятно, откуда может возникнуть ошибка. Предлагаю просто следить за моей мыслью, и у вас всё будет хорошо для сдачи лабораторной. :) (и код понятнее сделаем, и рабочим всё сделаем). При компиляции использовались ключи `-ansi` , `-pedantic` , `-Wall` и `-Werror`( могут и не использоваться : они всего лишь для самопроверки :D ).

### Сами структуры

1. Посмотрите на `DateOfBirth` и `Human`. Раз вы делаете `typedef`, то
   нужно придумать имя для вашего псевдонима, а у вас оно вообще
   отсутствует (не понимаю, как ваш C-компилятор этого не заметил, если
   это вообще C-компилятор).

   Исправляем, назначив то же имя, как и у самой структуры :

   ```
   typedef struct DateOfBirth {...} DateOfBirth;
   typedef struct Human {...} Human;
   ```
2. Когда вы работаете с такими структурами (да и ещё с файлами, которые
   с ней потенциально связаны), вам нужно (а по-моему, просто
   необходимо) использовать платформонезависимые типы (char-тип, к
   счастью, можно оставить). Список полей, в итоге, может быть
   следующим (заголовочный файл `stdint.h`).

   Для `DateOfBirth` :

   ```
   /*дни не могут быть отрицательными + за границы 256 дней по смыслу не выйти*/    
   uint8_t day;
   /*аналогично*/
   uint8_t month;
   /*то же самое, только для 2-х байтов*/
   uint16_t year;
   ```

   Для `Human` (аналогия с полей `DateOfBirth`):

   ```
   char id[8]; /*3456109 не 'влезет' в ваш 'char id[7]' : '\0' неуда вмещать*/
   char surname[20];
   char name[20];
   char patronymic[20];
   char sex[2];
   DateOfBirth dateOfBirth;
   uint8_t height;
   uint8_t weight;
   char city[15];
   char interests[30]; 
   char badHabits[20];
   char textMyself[30]; 
   uint8_t prefAgeMin;
   uint8_t prefAgeMax;
   char prefBadHab[20];
   ```
3. Если вы выделяете память для такой структуры в таком положении вещей, то
   вы, по факту выделяете больше, чем нужно (у вас такое есть в `checkSize`). Посмотрим размер "старого"
   `Human` :

   ```
   printf("%lu\n", sizeof(Human)); /*216*/
   ```

   А если внимательно посчитаете, то по факту получите 212 :) 
   Дело всё в
   [выравнивании](https://tproger.ru/translations/art-of-structure-packing/),
   но не будем заострять на этом внимание. Короче говоря, можете 'обвернуть' структуры (на всякий случай `DateOfBirth` тоже, а то мало ли, как машина 'захочет'), ипользуя `#pragma pack (push,1)` и `#pragma pack (pop)` перед определением и после определения "алиаса" для структуры соответственно, то есть :

   ```
   #pragma pack (push, 1)
   typedef struct DateOfBirth {...} DateOfBirth;
   #pragma pack (pop)
   ```

   и

   ```
   #pragma pack (push, 1)
   typedef struct Human {...} Human;
   #pragma pack (pop)
   ```

   Этот пункт не является обязательным, поскольку `pragma` разнится в
   зависимости от её реализации, но является желательным, если есть
   такая возможность и нельзя по-другому исправить структуру.

В итоге, ваши определения могут быть следующими :

```
#define ID_SIZE 8
#define SURNAME_SIZE 20
#define NAME_SIZE 20
#define PATRONYMIC_SIZE 20
#define SEX_SIZE 2
#define CITY_SIZE 15
#define INTERESTS_SIZE 30
#define BADHABITS_SIZE 20
#define TEXTMYSELF_SIZE 30
#define PREFBADHAB_SIZE 20

#pragma pack (push, 1)
typedef struct DateOfBirth {
    uint8_t day;
    uint8_t month;
    uint16_t year;
} DateOfBirth;
#pragma pack (pop)

#pragma pack (push, 1)
typedef struct Human {
    char id[ID_SIZE]; 
    char surname[SURNAME_SIZE];
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    char patronymic[PATRONYMIC_SIZE];
    char sex[SEX_SIZE];
    DateOfBirth dateOfBirth;
    uint8_t height;
    uint8_t weight;
    char city[CITY_SIZE];
    char interests[INTERESTS_SIZE]; 
    char badHabits[BADHABITS_SIZE];
    char textMyself[TEXTMYSELF_SIZE]; 
    uint8_t prefAgeMin;
    uint8_t prefAgeMax;
    char prefBadHab[PREFBADHAB_SIZE];
} Human;
#pragma pack (pop)
```

### checkSize

У вас там мало того, что память выделенная не освобождается, так и слишком запутанный и непереиспользуемый код.

> "сложнА-сложнААА" (c)

Предлагаю более подходящий вариант сигнатуры функции и её реализации (здесь уже "опустим" вопрос с кроссплатформенностью, ибо гораздо менее важно):

```
size_t get_humans_count ( const char* filename )
{
    FILE* fp;
    size_t lines_count = 0;
    char line[ MAX_LINE_SIZE ];

    fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if ( NULL == fp ) return 0;

    while ( fgets( line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fp ) != NULL )
    {
        if ( 0 == is_empty(line) )
        {
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }
        lines_count++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return lines_count / HUMAN_LINES_COUNT;
}
```

Реализация `is_empty` ( была позаимствована и немного переделана [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981510/getline-check-if-line-is-whitespace) ):

```
static int is_empty (const char *s) 
{
  while ( *s != '\0' ) 
  {
    if ( ! isspace( (unsigned char) *s ) ) return -1;
    s++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

`is_empty` нужен для того, чтобы вы не могли засчитать 'пустую' строку, как актуальную для записи её в структуру.

Протестируйте сами: оставьте где-нибудь 'пустые' строки, т.е. строки, содержащие только пробельный(-е) символ(-ы). В вашей реализации это бы засчиталось, и вы бы записали в какое-нибудь поле структуры 'пустую' строку.

В данном случае поля должны идти друг за другом, а иначе функция вернёт 0 ( единственный 'минус' тут в неудобочитаемости читаемого файла, потому что описания будут 'слиты', но реализация разделения - это просто и дело "десятое", и я не буду на этом останавливаться ).

### readingFromFile

Я "убил" весь день на то, чтобы правильно вывести прочитанные данные в структуру. Немного длиннее, но выглядит это всё более логично, а от такой структурированности маловероятно получить ошибку :

```
Human* get_humans_from ( const char* filename )
{
    FILE* fp;
    Human* humans_buffer;
    size_t humans_counter = 0;
    size_t humans_count = get_humans_count(filename);

    fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if ( NULL == fp || 0 == humans_count ) return NULL;

    humans_buffer = ( Human* ) malloc( sizeof(Human) * humans_count );
    if ( NULL == humans_buffer ) return NULL;

    while ( humans_counter < humans_count)
    {
        read_and_adjust_string( fp, humans_buffer[humans_counter].id );
        read_and_adjust_string( fp, humans_buffer[humans_counter].surname );
        read_and_adjust_string( fp, humans_buffer[humans_counter].name );
        read_and_adjust_string( fp, humans_buffer[humans_counter].patronymic );
        read_and_adjust_string( fp, humans_buffer[humans_counter].sex );

        humans_buffer[humans_counter].dateOfBirth.day = (uint8_t) read_and_get_ul ( fp ) ;
        humans_buffer[humans_counter].dateOfBirth.month = (uint8_t) read_and_get_ul ( fp );
        humans_buffer[humans_counter].dateOfBirth.year = (uint16_t) read_and_get_ul ( fp );
        humans_buffer[humans_counter].height = (uint8_t) read_and_get_ul ( fp );
        humans_buffer[humans_counter].weight = (uint8_t) read_and_get_ul ( fp );

        read_and_adjust_string( fp, humans_buffer[humans_counter].city );
        read_and_adjust_string( fp, humans_buffer[humans_counter].interests );
        read_and_adjust_string( fp, humans_buffer[humans_counter].badHabits );
        read_and_adjust_string( fp, humans_buffer[humans_counter].textMyself );

        humans_buffer[humans_counter].prefAgeMin = (uint8_t) read_and_get_ul ( fp );        
        humans_buffer[humans_counter].prefAgeMax = (uint8_t) read_and_get_ul ( fp );

        read_and_adjust_string( fp, humans_buffer[humans_counter].prefBadHab );
        print_human_info(humans_buffer[humans_counter]);
        humans_counter++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return humans_buffer;
}
```

Участвующие функции `read_and_adjust_string` и `read_and_get_ul` имеют следующие реализации :

```
static void read_and_adjust_string( FILE* opened_fp, char* line )
{
    fgets( line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, opened_fp );
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
}

static unsigned long int read_and_get_ul( FILE* opened_fp )
{
    char tmp_buf[MAX_LINE_SIZE] = {0};
    fgets( tmp_buf, MAX_LINE_SIZE, opened_fp );
    return strtoul( tmp_buf, NULL, 10 );
}
```

### loadToFile

Зачем вам в аргументах 'указатель на указатель'? Этого не нужно : нам всего лишь надо прочитать значения и вывести их в файл.

```
void load_humans_to ( const char* filename, Human* humans_buffer, size_t humans_count )
{
    FILE* fp;
    size_t humans_counter = 0;
    if ( NULL == humans_buffer  || 0 == humans_count ) return;

    fp = fopen( filename, "w" );
    if ( NULL == fp ) return;

    while ( humans_counter < humans_count )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].id );
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].surname );
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].name );
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].patronymic );
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].sex );
        fprintf( fp, "%u\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].dateOfBirth.day );
        fprintf( fp, "%u\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].dateOfBirth.month );
        fprintf( fp, "%u\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].dateOfBirth.year );
        fprintf( fp, "%u\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].height );
        fprintf( fp, "%u\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].weight );
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].city );
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].interests );
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].badHabits );
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].textMyself );
        fprintf( fp, "%u\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].prefAgeMin );
        fprintf( fp, "%u\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].prefAgeMax );
        fprintf( fp, "%s\n", humans_buffer[humans_counter].prefBadHab );

        humans_counter++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

### printOnConsole (опционально)

Реализовал более понятный и приятный 'вашему соседу' код для отображения (по крайней мере, мне так удобнее):

```
void print_humans_info( Human* humans_buffer, size_t size )
{
    size_t counter = 0;
    while ( counter < size )
    {
        printf("Human #%lu : \n",counter);
        print_human_info( humans_buffer[counter] );
        puts("");
        counter++;
    }   
}
```

Реализация `print_human_info`  следующая :

```
void print_human_info( Human hum )
{
    printf("\tID : %s\n", hum.id);
    printf("\tSurname : %s\n", hum.surname);
    printf("\tName : %s\n", hum.name);
    printf("\tPatronymic : %s\n", hum.patronymic);
    printf("\tSex : %s\n", hum.sex);
    printf("\tBirth day : %u\n", hum.dateOfBirth.day);
    printf("\tBirth month : %u\n", hum.dateOfBirth.month);
    printf("\tBirth year : %u\n", hum.dateOfBirth.year);
    printf("\tHeight : %u\n", hum.height);
    printf("\tWeight : %u\n", hum.weight);
    printf("\tCity : %s\n", hum.city); 
    printf("\tInterests : %s\n", hum.interests);
    printf("\tBad habits : %s\n", hum.badHabits);
    printf("\tAbout : %s\n", hum.textMyself);
    printf("\tPreferable min-age : %u\n", hum.prefAgeMin);
    printf("\tPreferable max-age : %u\n", hum.prefAgeMax);
    printf("\tPreferable bad habits : %s\n", hum.prefBadHab);
}
```

### Возможный 'main' для теста :

```
int main()
{
    char* src_filename = "database.txt";
    char* dst_filename = "database2.txt";
    size_t humans_count = get_humans_count(src_filename);
    Human* human_buffer = get_humans_from(src_filename);
    load_humans_to( dst_filename, human_buffer, humans_count );
    print_humans_info( human_buffer , humans_count );
    free(human_buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

### На будущее :

1. Чтобы лучше представлять информацию, нужно создать ещё один
   псевдоним :

   ```
   #pragma pack (push, 1)
   typedef struct People {
       size_t count;
       Human* humans;
   } People;
   #pragma pack (pop)
   ```

   Таким образом вам не придется постоянно 'вытягивать' и то, и то, а
   значит меньше аргументов на функции = лучшая удобочитаемость и
   чистота (но это уже вам задача, если желаете).
2. Задавайте вопрос более конкретно. Вы даже не сказали, в каком
   конкретно месте у вас возникают проблемы (у вас в коде не один
   `fclose`). Старайтесь описывать задачу **более** коротко (пожалуйста).

### Использованные заголовочные файлы:

```
stdio.h
stdint.h
stdlib.h
ctype.h
string.h
```

Comment: Благодарю за такой детальный разбор кода) По заданию мне нужно вместо массива структур сделать двусвязный список, но я думаю, что сделать это уже не составит труда.

Comment: @kravien, не за что. Двусвязный список - это ,конечно, уже на порядок проще, но , по-моему, лучше не добавлять в структуру `Human` какие-то адреса. Ради простоты видимости лучше создать какую-то структуру, скажем,  с именем `HumanEl` (лучше всего `Human`, а `Human` заменить ,например, на `HumInfo`) , и уже в этой структуре создать три поля, одно из которых - это сами данные про человека, а остальные два - указатели на сл. и предыдущие элементы. Ну вы поняли меня, вам будет так проще не ошибиться где-нибудь, по-моему :)

Answer (score 0):

Не смогли открыть, значит нечего закрывать.

```
    printf("Cannot open file"); // !!!
    //fclose(f);
```

Comment: файл открывается, поля структур заполняются, значит, файл все-таки открылся