# Array is not assignable в массиве структур

Tags: c, массивы, struct, malloc

Скажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка? Компилятор пишет:

> Array is not assignable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <intrin.h>

typedef struct Student{
    char *Name[255];
    char *Fullname[255];
    int lastmark;
} Student;

int main()
{
    Student *students;
    unsigned n,i;
    char *s[255];
    puts("Введите число студентов: ");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    puts("\n");
    students = (Student*) malloc(n*sizeof(Student));

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Имя %i-ого студента",i); scanf("%s", s);puts("\n");
        students[i].Name = (char*) malloc(strlen(s)+1);// Вот здесь ошибка
        printf("Фамилия %i-ого студента",i); scanf("%s", s);puts("\n");
        students[i].Fullname = (char*) malloc(strlen(s)+1);// и здесь
        printf("Оценка %i-ого студента",i); scanf("%i", i);puts("\n");
        students[i].lastmark = i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Update:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <intrin.h>

typedef struct Student{
    char Name[255];
    char Fullname[255];
    int lastmark;
} Student;

int main()
{
    Student *students;
    unsigned n,i,m;
    char *s[255];
    puts("Введите число студентов: ");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    puts("\n");
    students = (Student*) malloc(n*sizeof(Student));

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Имя %i-ого студента",i); scanf("%s", s);puts("\n");
        strcpy(students[i].Name, s);
        printf("Фамилия %i-ого студента",i); scanf("%s", s);puts("\n");
        strcpy(students[i].Fullname, s);
        printf("Оценка %i-ого студента",i); scanf("%i", &m);puts("\n");
        students[i].lastmark = m;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s %s %i",students[i].Name,students[i].Fullname,students[i].lastmark);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Update2 :

```
void PrintStudents(Student* students, int n){
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("%s %i %i\n", *(students[i]).name, *(students[i]).mark.Math, *(students[i]).mark.History);
    }
}

...
PrintStudents(&students,n);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым делом, `strlen` для матрицы не найти.

Я очень верю, что вы подразумевали не  `char* s[255];` , а  `char s[255]`;

Впринципе, везде эта проблема :)

```
typedef struct Student{
    char Name[255];
    char Fullname[255];
    int lastmark;
} Student;
```

`malloc` вам тут не надо, если вы создаёте строку именно таким образом.

**UPD** : всё гораздо проще, смотрите ваш исправленный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_BUF_SIZE 256

#pragma pack( push, 1 )
typedef struct Student{
    char Name[MAX_BUF_SIZE];
    char Fullname[MAX_BUF_SIZE];
    uint32_t lastmark;
} Student;
#pragma pack( pop )

static void read_student( Student* stud )
{
    printf("\tИмя студента : "); 
    scanf("%s", stud->Name);
    puts("");

    printf("\tФамилия студента : ");
    scanf("%s", stud->Fullname);
    puts("");

    printf("\tОценка студента : ");
    scanf("%u",&stud->lastmark);
    puts("");
}

Student* read_students()
{
    Student* students;
    size_t students_count,students_counter;

    puts("Введите число студентов: ");
    scanf("%lu",&students_count);
    students = (Student*) malloc( sizeof(Student) * students_count );
    puts("");

    for ( students_counter = 0; students_counter < students_count; students_counter++ )
    {
        printf("Cтудент %lu\n", students_counter);
        read_student(&students[students_counter]);
    }

    return students;
}

int main()
{
    Student* students = read_students();

    /*что-то сделали*/

    free(students); /*освободить не забудьте :) */

    return 0;
}
```

Не нужно заводить локальных переменных здесь.

Хотите создать строку во время работы программы, но размер заранее вам неизвестен - `char* arr;` а потом `malloc` где-нибудь. Известен - `char arr[размер];`

И ещё : рекомендую начать пользоваться платформонезависимыми типами (особенно важно это применять для структур).

Comment: А ещё, вопрос на "галочку", как его в функции вывести)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy , не до конца понял вас. Кого "его" ? Весь код? Его часть? Что функция должна делать?

Comment: массив student's, я в шапке добавил свою попытку )

Comment: Кстати, что за такое "pragma pack"? Мы просто в Университете ещё такого не проходили по программе (

Comment: Ответ исправил. Это ли то, что вы хотели?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy , по поводу pragma - [третий пункт, где я объясняю про структуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815168/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-fclose-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%a1/815705#815705). Это на всякий случай, чтобы у вас не выделилось больше памяти ввиду выравнивания.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy и не "fullname", а "surname" :) "Fullname" - это и имя, и фамилия вместе.

Comment: Преогромнейшое вам спасибо :3